# I have a program that calculates the first 200 prime numbers, but I do not understand a formula in it

Tags: java, primes

I need to write a code which should calculate the first 200 prime numbers, but I can't hand it in as long as I can't explain everything. I used a piece of code from the internet as reference (http://crab.rutgers.edu/~dhong/cs325/chapter3/PrimeNumber.java).

Whole code:

```
public class Opdracht3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int limiet = 200;
        int counter = 1;
        int testpriem = 3;
        boolean isPriem;

        while (counter <= limiet) {
            isPriem = true;
            for (int i = 2; i <= testpriem / 2; i++) {
                if (testpriem % i == 0) {
                    isPriem = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPriem) {
                System.out.println(counter + ": " + testpriem);
                counter++;
            }
            testpriem++;
        }
    }
}
```

Below part of code verifies if the number is a composite. If **testpriem** is composite, then comes out of the loop and starts over. Otherwise, it continues and prints the prime number **testpriem**.

The problem is here:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= testpriem / 2; i++) {
   if (testpriem % i == 0) {
      isPriem = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

I tested what happens to i, and one way or another it recognizes the divisor needed to calculate the composite. (With 4 divisor is 2, with 9 divisor is 3, with 221 divisor is 13) But I am flabbergasted as of why.

Any ideas?.

Comment: Not the answer, but an aside: you have misspellings of "prime" as "priem" all over your code. I'd recommend fixing them.

Comment: @EdCottrell they're not misspellings, the OP is dutch. Prime numbers are 'priemgetallen' in our language ;). OP: the definition of a prime number is that it can only be divided by itself or 1.

Comment: ... and must be greater than 1.

Comment: @EdCottrell I would if I didn't have to hand the assignment in in Dutch. ;) Normally I write in English when programming.

Comment: `%` (modulo) is rest by division (should that be unclear), `<= testpriem/2` as the largest prime factor of `testpriem` can only be half, `2*N == testpriem`

Comment: @nbokmans I am aware of that. I tried to completely program it by myself using those rules, but it turned out disastrous. (Hope I'm spelling that right...)

Comment: You need to understand the algorithm first and then the program. Read this at least: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @ACV Aah, I remember reading about this Sieve method. Didn't cross my mind to revisit it, stupid.... Thanks!

Comment: @nbokmans Ah, didn't realize that. Never mind!

Comment: @TheGravyNator Got it; sorry! Carry on. :)

Comment: @EdCottrell No problem at all! No way you could've known.

Comment: Not a very good implementation, in terms of the performance. But the thing about primes calculation - the better it is optimized for performance, the less you can understand what it actually does ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remember every number able to divide by its half or less. Consider number 7 it is possible divided by 1,2,3 because after 3, if try to divide number by 4 means 4x2 = 8 that is greater than 7. so it is optimum way to find divisor in this way. One more thing every number divided by 1 and number itself. so if number number is divided by 1 or itself then it is called prime so i starts from 2.

now consider testpriem =7 so you will get loop like

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 7 / 2(i.e 3); i++)
    {
            if(7 % i == 0)
            {
                isPriem = false; 
                break;
            }
```

so first time it checks 7%2=1 so condition false. again check for 7%3 = 1 again condition false. and now this condition full fills here i <= 7 / 2(i.e 3) so loop stopped and it result 7 number is prime

Comment: Okay, so what it is doing, it tests all the divisors that are natural numbers (I assume with the i++) and keeps doing that until the modulo of 7 % i is equal to zero? If that's the case, I think I understands what happens. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

the [`%` or ("remainder") operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) in Java divides one operand by another and returns the remainder as its result.  And of course if integer `x` is evenly divisible by another integer `y` (meaning `x/y =` some integer `z` with a remainder of zero), then `x` can not be prime.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I am aware how the % operator works and why it can calculate if the number is prime or not. But my problem was that the code finds a divisor for the numbers, and I am not able to figure out how.

Comment: ah, I see.  Then I am not sure what your exact problem is, sorry.  you know that if `testpriem % i == 0` then you have found a divisor and the loop breaks . Is that not the "why" that you are looking for?

Comment: Not a problem. I have my answer now, and the problem was that I didn't completely understand what the for loop did. (Testing, when false, move to next number)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `testpriem % i == 0`, it means that `i` divides testpriem, which means that `testpriem` is not a prime a number and `i`, is its first divider. % is the modulo operation, which is the rest of the division.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

The break stops the for loop and moves to the next position in the while loop.  So it does not restart the for loop for the current tested number.

The break is used for efficiency reasons. You could remove it and the algorithm would still work correctly but slower.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! This certainly helps with understanding what the hell is going on!